# Does obscuring personally identifiable and directory information avoid potential FERPA violations?

Tags: united-states, privacy, data-protection, education, ferpa

Say I have a database of students, each with a unique ID, GPA, placement test scores, and some demographic information (nothing personally identifiable). The ID is generated using a one-way cryptographic hash function that produces a string based on personally identifiable information. With this function, it is theoretically* impossible to figure out the original data, but it still preserves uniqueness. This is typically how passwords are stored; industry standard stuff.

**Does FERPA protect the release of educational records completely, or only when in combination with personally identifiable information?**

* theoretically. the development of quantum computing notwithstanding, the Sun will die long before anyone can figure the original data by testing every possible combination of letters and punctuation of unknown length. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

[snip detailed example]

Comment: Ask your college legal department; that's what they are there for.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch it is a relatively small community college, afaik there is no "legal department," and admin tends to shut down any conversation even remotely approaching FERPA-related risks. If this isn't the place for this question, then I'll just keep looking.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch This is a perfectly legitimate question about the scope and requirements of he FERPA law. We get, and answer, very similar question about the requirements of the GDPR all the time. This should not be closed as a request for specific legal advice See also https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/excessive-use-of-specific-legal-advice-closure-reason

Comment: @DavidSiegel I revised the question to be more generic. I thought a specific example would help communicate the technique involved, but I can see how that would be interpreted as a request for specific legal advice.

Comment: Thank You.I was considering such an edit myself, but it was better that you as the OP do it.

Comment: Only tangentially related to your question but the way anonymity is broken in cases like this is usually not through the hash function but rather through the geographic information plus some extra. Example: I know there is the kid from Indiana going to your college who got near perfect SAT scores. There is only one such entry in your data, so I get all his other data as well.

Comment: Quantum computing does not badly affect hash algorithms, only algorithms that are not in BQP, such as RSA and (EC)DH.

Comment: @quarague good point. I'll have to see how it might affect things, but I could see myself removing or collapsing any outliers to preserve anonymity.

Comment: @forest that's good to know. It looks like the hash algorithms I was planning to use are still considered quantum-safe, so my aside wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FERPA does not protect the release of educational records completely. [§99.31](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-34/subtitle-A/part-99/subpart-D/section-99.31) of the regulations spells out circumstances where disclosure of personally identifiable information
can be made without consent (a very long and complicated list).   Para (b) also states that the institution

> may release the records or information without the consent required by
> §99.30 after the removal of all personally identifiable information
> provided that the educational agency or institution or other party has
> made a reasonable determination that a student's identity is not
> personally identifiable, whether through single or multiple releases,
> and taking into account other reasonably available information.

An name or ID number is a clear example of PII. An anonymized set of grades from a transcript is not, and does not have the characteristics of

> Other information that, alone or in combination, is linked or linkable
> to a specific student that would allow a reasonable person in the
> school community, who does not have personal knowledge of the relevant
> circumstances, to identify the student with reasonable certainty;

That is, the law is not stated in terms of "could theoretically be traced back to the student" (since transcripts are under lock and key).

Answer (score 0):

### No

The problem with your dataset is that the sequence of grades for each individual are almost certainly unique (or nearly so). Someone who possessed a student’s educational history could most likely identify that person in your dataset.

Now, you may argue that that does not give the ‘hacker’ more information than they already had, however, that’s beside the point. The [regulations](https://studentprivacy.ed.gov/node/548/) identify personally identifiable information as:

> (f) Other information that, alone or in combination, is linked or linkable to a specific student that would allow a reasonable person in the school community, who does not have personal knowledge of the relevant circumstances, to identify the student with reasonable certainty;

Comment: If the only data stored is GPA, test scores, and demographics, you'd be hard-pressed to track someone back (given that there aren't any obvious minorities in demographics). Teachers are unlikely to remember exact grades, and if there are obvious outliers, I suppose you can't further obfuscate the data without running into discrimination issues, but given that it's a college, the dataset size should be large enough to prevent identification

Comment: I may indeed argue that it doesn't give anyone more information than they already had. As you quoted, "... *who does not have personal knowledge of the relevant circumstances* ..." so if they already have personal knowledge, they are excluded. Am I reading that right? And also to @belkarx's point, the dataset would likely be large enough to be "reasonably certain" that the data points of interest alone would not identify someone. Though that is a consideration I can apply when cleaning the data, possibly removing any student from the sample if it might identify them.

Comment: The cited law seems to contradict the answer. The regs don't ask whether "someone who possessed a student's education history" could identify that student, they ask whether a "reasonable person" "who does not have personal knowledge of the relevant circumstances" could identify the student. Someone holding the student's transcript is excluded from the analysis, and someone without the transcript can't identify the student. User6726's answer remains the best available.